# Shift-zoom border does not show after upgrade to v4.6.5

Tags: zooming, openlayers

When upgrading to OpenLayers 6.5, the shift-zoom rectangular border does not show anymore. The zoom function works in itself, but the border is gone. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The "border" is defined in the ol.css stylesheet file found in the css/ directory under openlayers. So be sure that your html includes that with something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
```

or define the sytle in-line like:

```
<style>
    .ol-box {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 2px;
      border: 2px solid blue;
    }
</style>
```